# How To Create a table From XML file C# and Call using Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, xml

First of all, I am still a beginner in coding (especially C# and dotnet environment). I am trying to create a table contains data get from an XML file. In order to access the data from the XML file, credentials are needed. The codes to access the XML is done at the codefile. The thing is, the XML file is displaying when I run the code, but I want to display the data into a table when I select an element for example "Title"

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String sUsername = "administrator";
    String sPassword = "123";

    String encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(sUsername + ":" + sPassword));
    HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("//pageurl");
    httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
    httpWebRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;

    HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

    if (webResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Stream responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.Default);
        string pageContent = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

        Debug.Print("Web response output as follows:");

        TextArea1.Text = pageContent;
    }
}
```

Above are the codes, and below is the front end

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<asp:TextBox id="TextArea1" TextMode="multiline" Columns="50" Rows="5" runat="server" />
</div>

</form>
```

Is there any way to call some of the xml data and display it in a table?

Answer (score 0):

Whether my understanding is correct , you need to display particular xml data in HTML page.

if its, Here is your answer.

Please Go through this website for reference.

http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/viewbag-in-asp.net-mvc

Store the data in ==>>>> ViewBag["any_name"]= data;

Then call ViewBag in html Page.

I hope its usefull to you

Thank u

Comment: Displaying the xml data in html is already done, by displaying the page content of the xml into html page. Now I need to view some of the data into a table. I dont know if viewbag can help but i will give it a try. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to deal with XML responses and you may find many tutorial related to work with XML in C#. As per your requirement I am providing you simple solution for your current problem.

Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="ms_tempo.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Data;

namespace ms_tempo
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://fakerestapi.azurewebsites.net/api/Authors");
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/xml";

            HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

            if (webResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Stream responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();

                dataSet.ReadXml(responseStream);

                gv.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
                gv.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the above example I have made a call to a fake rest API "https://fakerestapi.azurewebsites.net/api/Authors" which returns data in XML format. I have mentioned the type of data I want with this code

```
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/xml";
```

DataSet class can holds tables in it we are reading XML response and storing it into dataSet. Since the response only contains one xml document it generates one table within dataset which we are accessing using Tables(0); and finally passing the table to a grid view which shows data in table format in HTML. You can design the HTML table later on.

You can further learn about DataSet and DataTables class,also about grid view for better understanding.

Hope it helps